# Ajax AutocompleteExtender troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've been struggling all day with Ajax, and have no luck.  I know this question title has been asked before, but I've been pouring over many other posts about this, and none have the solution for me.  Let's start with the simplest scenario.

Having installed Ajax Toolbox, Version 15.1, I create a new web application, delete the content from the default page, drop a textbox onto it, and then try to drop an Ajax AutoCompleteExtender onto the textbox.  Result = no effect on the webpage at all.  The Toolbox has all the AjaxControlToolkit.15.1, but none of the Ajax controls can be dragged onto any forms.  (Other controls can be dragged correctly - only the AjaxControlToolkit controls have no effect)

Moving on to the more complicated scenario, I've tried to implement this manually, by adding a reference to the AjaxControlToolkit to the project - which requires a HDD search to find the dll, and adding a reference to this.

After manually adding the reference, then I can create a new page, and by editing the aspx source, I can create an AjaxCompleteExtender which builds and runs, but does not function correctly.  If I connect the AjaxCompleteExtender to a webservice, it does nothing.  If I connect it to a local function, it gives a strange list of autocomplete entries as follows...

```
<
D
O
C
T
Y
P
E
h
t
m
... etc...
```

I have put breakpoints in my ServiceMethod functions, and they never get called.

Here is the webpage for the version with the in-page function.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteSymbol"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="txtBox"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And here is the code behind this page.

```
namespace Jug2013
{
    public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string[] AutoCompleteSymbol(string partial, int count)
        {
            var retval = new List<string>();
            retval.Add("Hello");
            retval.Add("Hello2");
            retval.Add("Hello3");
            return retval.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the code of this version and the web service version many times against online examples, and tried many different variations that I've found in sample code.  In final desperation, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Ajax, but still no luck anywhere.

Comment: Actually you are getting an error. See the console of your browser to check what is the error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Firefox.  I looked in the Web Console, and could only see the POST http://localhost:49882/TestForm/AutoCompleteSymbol. (occurs each time I type a new character)  Checked the Browser Console, and there's nothing there.  There's a few errors/warnings on page load, but they don't look relevant.

Comment: yes where you see post and url of the page there you should see the response.Expand this url in console.

Comment: Looks like a successful response.  Screenshots at www.surfplan.com.au/temp/response1.png and www.surfplan.com.au/temp/response2.png.  On another note, Internet explorer debugger showed a message about a long-running script.

Comment: After yet another uninstall/reinstall of the Ajax Toolkit, the drag-drop of AJAX controls is working now, but AutoCompleteExtender is still giving the same weird result in a completely new solution+project.  So, it's not something wrong deep in the bowels of my project.  The only change from the default project is the code shown above.